# Tailoring a jacket with a $1$-inch lapel notch at a horizontally-symmetric $40^\circ$ angle

Tags: geometry

I'm having a jacket custom made with a custom lapel.  I want the lapel to have a 1" lapel notch with a horizontally symmetric $40^\circ$ angle like this:

[image: Picture]

My tailor says that the notch angle is dependent on a set of other measurements.  Here's a picture of the diagram he provided to me:

[image]

Here's a key to the labelled measurements in the diagram:

A. Shoulder Seam to Lapel Point

B. Shoulder Seam Perpendicular to centre Notch

C. Top Notch Length

D. Bottom Notch Length

E. Shoulder Seam to Collar Point

Some other parameters:

- The vertical measurement between the top of the shoulder seam (starting point of A) and the inner point of the lapel notch (C/D) should be 2.75".
- the collar point and lapel point should be vertically aligned

> What values should I provide to my tailor for measurement points A through E in order to achieve the overall desired measurements?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a friend whose son was a math major and she returned the following image with notes:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/elul3dpruznkci7/File%20Sep%2018%2C%2011%2041%2009%20PM.png?dl=0

Rounding to the closest 1/4" yields the following measurements:

- A - 3.25"
- B -
- C - 1"
- D - 1"
- E - 2.5"

Her son did not provide the measurement of "B" b/c he needed the slope angle of the shoulder which I didn't provide.  Do the calculations on the image url above look correct?  Can you solve for "B" given a shoulder slope of 25 degrees?